# Why data query speed after data synchronization of single node to cluster nodes is much slower than to single node of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: triggers, cluster-computing, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask about the latest 1.0 cluster version of Apache IoTDB. When I use tsfile to synchronize the data in the single node to the cluster nodes of this version, the query speed of the cluster version is far slower than that of a single node. (like only 1/5 speed of single node) However if the data is synchronized from a single node to a single node, there will be no such problem. I would like to know what configuration parameters need to be changed to solve this problem?

How to deal this question ? Someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first time you query using Apache IoTDB? All data needs to be loaded from the disk, so you can check again after a while. Or you can check whether there is out-of-order data that you needs to be sync. If so, you can use `merge` to eliminate out-of-order data, and see if the sync process becomes faster